# tree traversal in spiral form in python

Tags: python, binary-tree, tree-traversal

```
def spiral(root):
    if not root:
        return
    s1=[]
    s2=[]
    s1.append(root)
    while s1 or s2:
        while s1:
            n=s1[0]
            s1.pop(0)
            print(n.val,end=' ')
            if n.left:s2.append(n.left)
            if n.right:s2.append(n.right)
        while s2:
            n=s2[0]
            s2.pop(0)
            print(n.val,end=' ')
            if n.right:s1.append(n.right)
            if n.left:s1.append(n.left)
```

At the last level the answer is opposite of what is required. If the required is: `1 2 3 7 6 5 4`, the answer that function giving is: `1 2 3 5 4 7 6`.
So what's the error?

Comment: You probably want to insert elements at the beginning of the list instead of appending them at the end. Use `insert` and specify index 0.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki nope not working

Comment: Then you should post some code that we can run and test. Your code uses some data structure for tree that is not included in the code.